# Can a Web Api project be deployed to Azure without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ado.net, azure-web-app-service

I have a functioning ASP.NET Web Api project that makes use of ADO.NET for it's data access rather than Entity Framework (EF). More specifically, data is obtained by using the SQL Command and a DataReader.

All of the tutorials I have seen regarding deploying a Web Api project to Azure make reference to using EF Code First migrations. In my situation I already have a defined SQL database instead of having one created and seeded by Entity Framework.

Is the use of EF mandatory when deploying to Azure or is it just a preferred method? Could I still deploy my API to Azure where my database is pre-defined and ADO.NET is used to access the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF is not mandatory for Azure Websites / Web API. It's just the Microsoft preferred method in demonstrations :)

You can use the common ADO.NET provider (or any kind of provider) to access your database.

Regards,

Florent.